# Camel Cache Entry Info and Configuration

Tags: java, apache-camel, ehcache

I have two questions about camel-cache (http://camel.apache.org/cache.html) and Ehcache 2.x,

1. When a get operation (CamelCacheGet) is performed, is there any way to get the
   creation time of the entry or the duration it has remaining on the cache?
2. If the cache configuration changes dynamically (time to live, time to idle, etc) what happens to the TTL and TTI of the entries that are already in the cache before it changes? It changes to the new configuration or remains the old configuration when the entries were created?

Thanks in advance